# Show that $d(u,v)=\exp(-\max\{j\ge 0, u_k=v_k \space\mbox{for}\space 0\le k\le j\})$ is a distance over $E=\Bbb{R}^\Bbb{N}$.

Tags: inequality, metric-spaces

> Let $E=\Bbb{R}^\Bbb{N}$, $u=(u_k)_{k\in\Bbb{N}}$ and $v=(v_k)_{k\in\Bbb{N}}$.
>
> Define $$
> d(u,v) = \left\{
>     \begin{array}{ll}
>         \exp(-V(u,v)) & \mbox{if}\quad u\ne v \\
>         0 & \mbox{otherwise}
>     \end{array}
> \right.
> $$
>
> where $V(u,v)=\max\{j\ge 0, u_k=v_k \space\mbox{for}\space 0\le k\le j\}$ with $u\ne v$.
>
> *Show that* $V(u,w)\ge\min \bigl(V(u,v), V(v,w)\bigr)$ and $d$ is a distance over $E$.

Progress:

1. Let $u,v,w\in E$, if $V(u,v)$ and $V(v,w)$ are $\ge j$ we have
   $V(u,w)\ge j$.

Indeed, $V(v,w)\ge j$ means that for all $0\le k\le j$ we have $u_k=v_k$ and $V(v,w)\ge j$ means that for all $0\le k\le j$ we have $v_k=w_k$.

Then for all $0\le k\le j$ we have $V(u,w)\ge j$. Correct? How can I continue?

2. Clearly $d$ takes is values in $\Bbb{R}^+$ and $d(u,v)=d(v,u)$ and $d(u,u)=0$ implies $u=0$ by definition of $d$.

Now by taking $u\ne w$ we have $d(u,w)=\exp(-V(u,w))$, I juste need to use 1) for triangular inequality point.

**EDIT:** Ok so I have to prove that $V(u,w)\ge\min \bigl(V(u,v),V(v,w)\bigr)$ not the product. I think I am not correct for 1) we are not dealing with the same $k$, are we?

Comment: Well, $V(u,w)\ge\min \bigl(V(u,v),V(v,w)\bigr)$ hence $d(u,w)\le\max \bigl(d(u,v),d(v,w)\bigr)\le\ldots$

Comment: @Did If I understand correctly, I have to prove that $V(u,w)\ge \min\bigl(V(u,v),V(v,w) \bigr)$ not the product?

Comment: Indeed. Basic counterexamples show that the inequality $V(u,w)\ge\min \bigl(V(u,v)V(v,w)\bigr)$ is unsound, whatever the min means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typical *ultrametric*, a function $d$ that satisfies 
$$d(u,w)\le \max(d(u,w), d(v,w)) \tag{1}$$
[which is stronger than the triangle inequality].

Let $m = \min \bigl(V(u,v),V(v,w)\bigr)$; then

1. $u_j=v_j$ for $0\le j\le m$, and
2. $v_j=w_j$ for $0\le j\le m$
3. From 1 and 2, $u_j = w_j$ for $0\le j\le m$
4. Hence $V(u,w)\ge m$

Comment: Using the fact that $V(u,w)$ is the length of the maximal initial segment where $u$ and $w$ the problem becomes much easier. Anyway I just want to understand the english behind $u$ and $v$ agree on : Can you explain? Thanks

Comment: This means English reformulation wasn't helpful. I changed it back to symbols.